# IntegrationTest isolation fails in springboot 2.2.2.RELEASE (Error dopping tables after each SpringBootTest)

Tags: hibernate, h2, spring-boot-test

Our app is working in 2.0.4 release. After upgrade to 2.2.2.RELEASE we see integration tests failing. I suspect that there is some misconfiguration, and each integration test simply does not clean after itself or there is extra initialization which weren't here before. I really do not know how to fix it properly.

To be specific. Each test works when invoked separately. When executed all of them we do see errors like:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop table somewhere.sometable if exists" via JDBC Statement
...
caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Cannot drop "SOME_TABLE" because "FKKJEJC7GUX6OTX5NGANQCMN83R, FK7WLRCFA21PY7CI3R4OL1OWODT, FKQPMY4YOVD3D6HBNT0XX92149P, FK1TG6AMM2NSM6UJTO9EJHPJIXY, FKLPTBKDKFCHE72RJ5RRRIH4ORJ" depends on it; SQL statement:
```

and

```
2019-12-16 21:11:00.075 org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry  : The MBean registry cannot be disabled because it has already been initialised
```

which suggests me, that we're trying to re-initialize something already initialized + there is wrong order of drops in hibernate initialization. But I really cannot see anything wrong on our side. Lets show some excerpts:

annotations of test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(...)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SomeIT {
```

tests are executed via:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    <forkCount>0</forkCount>
    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>integration-test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>verify</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>verify</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and application.properties for tests:

```
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true

#this disables option to have opened tx in view IIUC. We don't rely on that, so this just removes warning logging from console.
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

#used to select db initialization scripts.
spring.datasource.platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:somewhere;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=create schema if not exists somewhere
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.h2.Driver

#this is probably needed for @DataJpaTest: I have no idea how to configure @DataJpaTest so that it can run with
#autoconfigured H2 db, probably it's caused by having schema defined in entities. Anyways @DataJpaTest fails to
#create schema. So alternative is to configure one DB for whole app here, and this option forces all @DataJpaTest not to
#replace this configuration with autoconfigured db.
spring.test.database.replace=none
```

Tested changes:

- I changed create to create-drop if it helps in any way and no, it
  does not help in any way.
- I tried to @DirtiesContext on class level for every IT test, which is what I'd expect anyways, that context is created/killed with every IT test class, but that did not help either.
- I tried to remove `replace=none`, but that just kills all unit tests(because schema is not created), and does not help in any way to integration tests.

Current workaround: well all I was able to come up with is not to reuse db. Which with `replace=none` is possible only via:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:somewhere${random.uuid};DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=create schema if not exists somewhere
```

but I deeply hate this "solution". What can cause incorrect db re-initialization / missing cleanups / or what the cause of all this could be?

(edit: if you know better title to this question, please suggest. Thanks).

Comment: I have the same problem and I really hope this question will get more attention. Maybe change the title to something more specific like `Hibernate: Error dopping tables after each SpringBootTest`

Comment: you can cheat it in two ways. randomize datasource url, as shown, or use ddl-auto=update. Both will remove symptoms (exceptions), but the cause will remain: DB created just once and shared for all tests. I don't know, maybe this is changed behavior between springboot versions or regression

Comment: there has to be a solution for this. do you only use a data.sql with insert statements or with schema creation? maybe if you explicitly create and drop the schema it will work?

Comment: I tried to drop the tables explicitly in my data.sql with `ddl-auto=create` and it works if you use the correct order. But know i have to specify the schema creation to, which i would like to avoid. 

So I opened a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561551/hibernate-h2-specify-drop-table-order) to your post: Hopefully this will bring us closer to the solution.

Comment: no, we don't use data.sql or schema.sql. About another your comments: when you start your test, spring initializes your db. Then you drop all tables manually. And then ... nothing. That's to be expected. If spring decided to initilize db just once for all tests, and then you decided to drop all manually, spring won't intervene, but it will not force him to reinit the db for you.

Comment: For me, When I ran the mvn test, it inited the tables fine (as expected) by dropping them "if exists" and then creates them.  
When both the tests had the spring profile, surefire does not try to re-initialize the h2 db before the second test. However, when the profiles are different, surefire tries to re-init the tables when it starts the second test. Since the first test had not cleaned up the h2 db, the second test failed, since the sequence of drop tables is wrong and that failed. Adding the right drop script is a good solution. But watch out for profile differences as well

Answer (score 11):

I was getting the same error after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.2.1 from 2.2.0. It looks 2.2.1 has updated the h2 dependency to 1.4.200. (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.2.1.RELEASE)

H2 v1.4.200 has a change to update its DROP TABLE strategy (https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/1912). But hibernate's H2Dialect class has not been updated accordingly (both version  5.4.9,  5.4.10).

I extended the H2Dialect class to tell Hibernate org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaMigrator to drop the constraints as follows to solve the problem.

**Updates:**

```
spring:
    jpa:
        database-platform: mypackage.MyH2Dialect


import org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect;

public class MyH2Dialect extends H2Dialect {

    @Override
    public boolean dropConstraints() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsIfExistsAfterAlterTable() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Related issues:**

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13711

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/3093

https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/1912

**See also:**
org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.StandardForeignKeyExporter.getSqlDropStrings( )

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and unfortunately [Melkor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59602781/2477111) did not work for us because our schema was too complex to write a script dropping tables in a correct order.

H2 supports [dropping all objects](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#drop_all_objects) regardless of their dependencies, so the following script can reset the whole db.

src/test/resources/drop-tables.sql

```
DROP ALL OBJECTS
```

Then, specify the test properties to use the script to drop tables

src/test/resources/application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source=script
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source=drop-tables.sql
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012915/607637 that works for me. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to let you know that I found a work-around for this problem. With `javax.persistence` properties you can define a drop script which will be executed before the automatic schema creation.

This enables you to specify the order in which the tables have to be dropped (dependend tables first). Maybe playing around with these could help you. Note that they replace the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl` property.

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action=drop-and-create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source=script-then-metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source=drop-tables.sql
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012915/607637 that works for me. Let me know if this works for you.