# Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot drop table 'link' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'FK336ctjyksuuwnpmffcogcdyet' on table 'vote'

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I have this error in my spring boot application with mysql database for two days so please help,
I tried to drop the foreign key and several things and follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66118558/14782961) the problem solved for a moment then back ,it didn't work for me.

link.java code

```java
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Link extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter a title.")
    private String title;

    @NonNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter a url.")
    @URL(message = "Please enter a valid url.")
    private String url;

    // comments
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "link")
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "link")
    private List<Vote> votes = new ArrayList<>();

    private int voteCount = 0;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public void addComment(Comment comment) {
        comments.add(comment);
    }

    public String getDomainName() throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri = new URI(this.url);
        String domain = uri.getHost();
        return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
    }

    public String getPrettyTime() {
        PrettyTime pt = BeanUtil.getBean(PrettyTime.class);
        return pt.format(convertToDateViaInstant(getCreationDate()));
    }

    private Date convertToDateViaInstant(LocalDateTime dateToConvert) {
        return java.util.Date.from(dateToConvert.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }
}
```

vote.java

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Vote extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private short direction;

    @NonNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Link link;

}
```

schema.sql

```sql
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `springit`; 
USE `springit`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comment`;

CREATE TABLE `comment` (
                           `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                           `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                           `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                           `last_modified_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                           `last_modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                           `body` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                           `link_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
                           PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                           KEY `FKoutxw6g1ndh1t6282y0fwvami` (`link_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `link`;
CREATE TABLE `link` (
                        `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                        `last_modified_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `last_modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                        `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

application.properties

```
logging.level.com.vega.spring_start=DEBUG

# info about our application
info.application.name=Springit
info.application.description=Reddit clone using Spring Boot 2
info.application.version=0.0.1

# mysql settings
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springit?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=something
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
#h2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:springit
#spring.datasource.name=springit


#spring.security.user.roles=ADMIN
#spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings= false

#actuator
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=when_authorized


#spring.batch.job.enabled=false

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

the exceptions:

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at com.example.spring_start.SpringStartApplication.main(SpringStartApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:451) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:200) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> ... 14 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Console' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of URL [file:/C:/Users/msys/Desktop/spring_start/target/classes/schema.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `link`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot drop table 'link' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'FK336ctjyksuuwnpmffcogcdyet' on table 'vote'.
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:259) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:233) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> ... 19 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of URL [file:/C:/Users/msys/Desktop/spring_start/target/classes/schema.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `link`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot drop table 'link' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'FK336ctjyksuuwnpmffcogcdyet' on table 'vote'.
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> ... 59 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of URL [file:/C:/Users/msys/Desktop/spring_start/target/classes/schema.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `link`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot drop table 'link' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'FK336ctjyksuuwnpmffcogcdyet' on table 'vote'.
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:617) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2021) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.ifAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2032) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.h2Console(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> ... 60 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of URL [file:/C:/Users/msys/Desktop/spring_start/target/classes/schema.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `link`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot drop table 'link' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'FK336ctjyksuuwnpmffcogcdyet' on table 'vote'.
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.java:51) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:444) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> ... 75 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of URL [file:/C:/Users/msys/Desktop/spring_start/target/classes/schema.sql]: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `link`; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot drop table 'link' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'FK336ctjyksuuwnpmffcogcdyet' on table 'vote'.
> at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:622) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:202) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.createSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:101) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:63) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> ... 90 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot drop table 'link' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'FK336ctjyksuuwnpmffcogcdyet' on table 'vote'.
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
> at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:601) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot drop table referenced by a foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117706/cannot-drop-table-referenced-by-a-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: @SternK 
No, I'm the one who asks the question.

it works for one time and then the problem return.

Comment: @SternK
I try to follow a course for a spring boot.. the teacher doesn't do anything like recreating vote table. I don't know why I have the problem!

Answer (score 0):

See duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/a/66118558/1032890.

Did you try it like this?

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `springit`;
USE `springit`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comment`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `link`;

CREATE TABLE `link` (
                        `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                        `last_modified_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `last_modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                        `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `comment` (
                           `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                           `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                           `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                           `last_modified_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                           `last_modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                           `body` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                           `link_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
                           PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                           FOREIGN KEY `FKoutxw6g1ndh1t6282y0fwvami` (`link_id`)
                                   REFERENCES `link`(`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```